# To prove $adj(adjA)=A$ for a Singular matrix of order $3 \times 3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I could prove $$adj(adj(A))=|A|^{n-2}A$$ for any Non singular matrix $A$ of order $n \times n$ as follows:

we have $$adj(A)=|A|A^{-1} \tag{1}$$ Taking Inverse on both sides we get

$$(adj(A))^{-1}=\frac{1}{|A|}A \tag{2}$$

Replacing $A$ with $adj(A)$ in $(1)$ and using $(2)$ we get

$$adj(adj(A))=|adjA|(adj(A))^{-1}=\frac{|adjA|}{|A|}A=|A|^{n-2}A$$

But how can we deduce the result of $adj(adjA))$ when $A$ is Singular?

Answer (score 1):

This is false. If $A$ has rank $1$ then $adj(A)=0$ and hence 
$$adj(adj(A))=0 \neq A$$

For example, use 
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

**Added** If $rank(A)=2$, then the nullspace of $A$ is one dimensional. The relation 
$$A (adj(A))=0$$
then implies that the columns of $adj(A)$ are in the null space, and hence they are scalar multiples of a fixed vectors. Thus $rank(adj(A))=1$ and hence $adj(adj(A)=0$.

Therefore, you can prove:

**Claim:** If $n \geq 3$ and $A$ is an $n \times n$ singular matrix then
$$adj(adj(A))=0 .$$

Proof: If $rank(A)=n-1$ then then the nullspace of $A$ is one dimensional. By the same argument as above you get $rank(adj(A))=1$, and hence , since $n \geq 3$, $$adj(adj(A))=0 .$$

If $rank(A)<n-2$ then all the $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ minors are $0$ and hence
$$adj(A)=0$$

Comment: So if $n \ge 3$ and $A$ is Singular $adj(adj(A))=0$ and if $n=2$ then $adj(adj(A)=A$

Answer (score 0):

One way is by continuity. Replace $A$ by $A+tI$. This will be nonsingular
when $t$ is small and nonzero. Then let $t\to0$.